# Create a directory with a specific group on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, mkdir

I have set up a small FTP server for a project I'm working on.

However, when "user1" create a directory, that directory user and groups are both "user1".
What I'd like to get is a directory that belong to user1, but is owned by a specific group.

How can I do this ? Can something like a umask help me, or does it need to be set up in the FTP client (FileZilla) ?

Answer (score 0):

Add users that allowed to access ftp directory to the group `ftp`

```
usermod -a -G ftp user1
usermod -a -G ftp user2
...
usermod -a -G ftp userN
```

and change ownership of ftp directory to `ftp` group

```
chown -R ftp:ftp /path/to/ftp/dir
```

You may want to adjust permission too

```
chmod 775 /path/to/ftp/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

To influence the require behaviour, you need to

1. Make the parent directory be owned with the group you need.
2. Have the so-called "sticky bit" set on it.

On Linux, this setting will make sure the new items created in the directoty with the sticky bit set be owned with the owning group of that directory rather than the primary group of the process created that item.

So basically you need to

```
# chgrp that_group path/to/the/target/dir
# chmod g+s $_
```

Note that `umask` settings have no bearing on sticky bits, so you'll need
to make sure `umask` settings of your users will at least not mask `g+rx` otherwise the directories they will create there won't be traversable/readable by the owning group.

[Further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit).